# Is Singular value decomposition suitable for solving matrix equations Ax=b?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

Consider the following equation $A_{n\times n}x_{n\times 1}=b_{n\times 1}$. This is a nonhomogeneous linear system, but the SVD is "specialized" for solving homogeneous systems, like $Ax=0$.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Relation_to_nonhomogeneous_systems) Wikipedia article states that the mapping from the solution of a homogeneous system can be mapped to a solution of the nonhomogeneous system. So, if $v$ is the solution to $Ax=0$ and $p$ is any solution of $Ax=b$, then the entire solution can be described as $p+v$.

I'm confused about that description, as it indicates that I have to solve both systems in order to make that connection, which doesn't make sense.

So, can the linear system, depicted in its matrix form as $Ax=b$, be solved by applying the single value decomposition on its component $A$? If yes, how, if not, why?

Comment: The SVD of a $n\times n$ matrix gives you it's inverse for free, so you can trivially solve any system of the form $Ax=b$ knoing the SVD of $A$. Maybe you should clarify your question?

Comment: @AlexR That is the answer to my question. However, I'd like some more clarification as I still don't see how I get the inverse for free. The SVD of $M$ is $M=U\Sigma V*$, what constitutes the inverse? The $n\times n$ case is obviously different, how does the above statement look like in that case?

Comment: Note that both $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal and $\Sigma$ is diagonal. $$M^{-1}=V\Sigma^{-1}U^\ast$$